# How to exit from a node-kafka consumer if no message received within pre-defind time

Tags: node.js

I have written a node-Kafka consumer. This works absolutely fine if there is any message available in the topic but gets blocked forever if there is no new message available in the topic. I want to close the consumer and call a callback function if no message is received within time-frame. Is there a way to handle this scenario.

Below is my code snippet for consumer:

consumer = new kafka.HighLevelConsumer(
          client,
          [
              { topic: topic, partition: 0, fromOffset: false, fetchMaxWaitMs: 100}
          ],
          {
              autoCommit: false
          }
      );
      consumer.on('message', function (message) {
        console.log("received message", message);
        returnArray.push(message.value);
        if(message.offset == (message.highWaterOffset -1)){
          consumer.close(true, function(err, message) {
            console.log("consumer has been closed..");
          });

```
      callback(returnArray);
    }
```

Thanks,
Ankit

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you find a solution?